# How do I create a simple unit test using junit or testng for a Queue interface class?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, testng

I am new to Java but I'm doing my best to learn as fast as possible. I created a class in Eclipse using the Queue Interface and I created an array of elements (in my case animals). To this array I added a new element called "tiger".

I got stuck in the moment when I wanted to create a new class using testng/junit and trying to add a simple unit test to check if the new element "tiger" was added correctly to the array list. My queue code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String animals[] = {"cat","dog","pony","horse","cheetah"};
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(queue, animals);
    System.out.println(queue);
    queue.add("tiger");
    System.out.println(queue);}
```

Please help, I would be happy for any advise.

Comment: I would recommend to first learn OO programming. unit testing means testing of seperate units (in java code: methods/classes/...). to check that if an application fails, where it fails.
As long as all of your code is in one single method, the advantage of unit testing is brought down to "does it work or not?"

Comment: What specifically is the matter you want to test? Is this your own `LinkedList` type? If so, then to make a test for it you will need to write an entirely separate class that follows a set of rules established for your test framework of choice. Think of each test as if it had its own `main` method somewhere (that you can't see and shouldn't really think about other than the fact that it exists), that in the end will call your test method (again, for now it's of no concern as to how it will do it - just know that it will, if you write your test correctly).

Answer (score 0):

From your code I would recommend:

1. First, put that main code in another method, and if possible in
   another class.
2. Not a requirement but avoid the static in the new method.
3. Read about unit testing
4. Use jUnit5 for unit testing, is very popular
5. Probably, more below, you want to read about doubles (like Mockito)

In your case, and I can tell you that your code is not "test friendly", you want to test if the element is in the Queue, using its own methods, or using something like Mockito to verify the add was called with the value you want to test, but for you to understand this, you should learn more about doubles, mocks, stubs.

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //Given
    String animals[] = {"cat","dog","pony","horse","cheetah"};
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(queue, animals);

    //When
    queue.add("tiger");

    //Then
    assertThat(queue, hasSize(6));
    assertEquals("tiger",((LinkedList<String>) queue).getLast());
}
```